# What technical details exist about the Soyuz TMA spacecraft and its Simvol Displays & Cockpit Controls?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, instrument

I am looking for technical details about the soyuz tma, simvol displays and cockpit controls in general. Something like the NASA familiarization manuals, but for Soyuz. And in english :)

Can anyone point me to some resources? I've already seen that student simulator of docking (excellent) and own the Haines workshop manual, but more would be appreciated. I've even taken a lot of screenshots from Gravity movie.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good manual "Soyuz Crew Operations Manual (SoyCOM) (ROP-19) (Final)
, Yu. A. Gagarin Cosmonaut's Training Center, NAS15-10110, 0004AE7a
(ROP-19), April 1998" which is in English, although translated, it's an OK job.

You can find a copy at this [page](https://www.infosondas.com/2017/04/pdf-soyuz-crew-operations-manual-soycomrop-19final/).

[image]

Comment: Works for me, and is a great source of info, thanks very much!

Comment: Great news! I'll try a different browser. I have wanted to find one online so that I can use it for a reference in answers - I only have a paper copy.'